# how to change date format in java?

Tags: java

i am getting my date input as a string in the format `dd-mm-yy` through jsp page. Because this format is better to understand . But now i want to store the date in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format in my database. I am using the following code.

```
try
    {       
    String s="30-04-2013";
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    d1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(s);
    System.out.println(d1);
    System.out.println(ft.format(d1));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }
```

My Jsp date format is `dd-mm-yy`, but it gives answer as

```
Tue Oct 04 00:00:00 IST 35
0035-10-04 00:00:00
```

what is my mistake?
can tell me anyone please

Thank you.

Comment: A date in a database doesn't have any format. Use PreparedStatement.setDate() or PreparedStatement.setTimestamp() to store a Date or Timestamp object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(s);
```

should be

```
d1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(s);
```

because the input date String you've provided `String s="30-04-2013";` is of the format, `dd-MM-yyyy`. Hence, to parse this, you need to give `dd-MM-yyyy` format in your SDF.

Comment: And by using `setLenient(false)` it would also pick up the issue quicker since your date gets 'rolled over' to fit your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format in your code from `yyyy-MM-dd` to `dd-MM-yyyy`. A simple debug would have solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

See below the working program.  See the parse and format method.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class DateParsing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = "30-04-2013";
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat nt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            System.out.println(nt.format(ft.parse(s)));
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: NO! you use lower case m for minutes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to pass the Date object to **format()** method of SimpleDateFormat class instead of passing string to it

just try to do like as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formatted_date = ft.format(new Date());
System.out.println(formatted_date);
```

let me know the status

happy coding

Comment: `d1` is a Date object only.